# Autowiring and annotation configuration in Spring

Tags: java, spring, annotations, autowired

I have 2 components `A` and `B`. `A` depends on `B`. I wrote something like:

```
public class A {
    private B b;
    @Autowired
    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}

@Component
public class B {}

new XmlBeanFactory(new FileSystemResource("./spring.xml")).getBean(A.class);
```

config

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com">
</context:component-scan>

<bean class="com.A" autowire="byType" />
```

It worked perfectly well. Now I want configure `A` by annotations too. So I add @Component annotation to `A`

```
@Component
public class A {
    private B b;
    @Autowired
    public void setB(B b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

And removed `A` description from configuration. So it just

```
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan
    base-package="com">
</context:component-scan>
```

But B doesn't injected anymore. Probably I should specify autowiring type or smt like that. So how I can fix it?

Comment: Do you get an exception or is `B` just `null`? Do both classes sit in the same package?

Comment: @Benjamin Muschko Just `null`. In same package. I put all my classes in the `com` package

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use `ApplicationContext` instead of plain `BeanFactory`. Seems like `BeanFactory` does not run post processors, including the one looking for `@Autowired` annotation. I will try to find a piece of documentation for that, in the meantime try:

```
new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/spring.xml").getBean(B.class);
```

BTW `@Autowired` is completely valid on setters, constructors, fields, etc. ([source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html)):

> Marks a constructor, field, setter method or config method as to be autowired by Spring's dependency injection facilities.

Comment: This is the document you are after http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#context-introduction-ctx-vs-beanfactory

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try

```
@Component
public class A {
    @Autowired
    private B b;
    }
}

@Component
public class B {}
```

You can refer to example on below link:
http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/spring/spring3/ioc/autoscanig.html

Comment: I have same trouble with this solution.